# Flash CS5.5: Error 1046. I can't find another way to do it

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Essentially, I have 6 balls, and when my showBalls() function runs, I want each ball (each are a movieclip) to run its animation and tween to the correct place. I want them to do it in order though. So 1 ball tweens, then the next, then the next and so on.

I've used a bunch of if statements because switch wouldn't work, but now it just keeps throwing me Error 1046 and telling me that "Event" was not found or not compile-time constant.

I can't see anyway around this and it's frustrating me.

Here's some code for you all. It's probably messy as hell and there'll be a much easier way to do this. But I'm pretty new to AS3 so I can't see any other way.

I have tried to find the answer on here and somebody told me to un-nest the functions. So I did. I've not had a problem with one nest but I tried two here and it didn't work. So I un-nested, but to no avail. If there is a way around this, i'd be grateful for guidance.

So yeah, first ball shown, tweens, once tween reaches final frame, it stops and the number associated with it shows. Repeat for following 6 balls.

```
function showNumbers()
{
    var count:int = 0;
    var showTimer:Timer = null;
    showTimer = new Timer(3125,8);
    showTimer.start();
    showTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, showBalls);
    function showBalls(Event:TimerEvent)
    {
        ball1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ball1stop);
        ball2.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ball2stop);
        ball3.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ball3stop);
        ball4.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ball4stop);
        ball5.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ball5stop);
        ball5.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ball6stop);
        bonusBall.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bonusBallstop);

        function ball1stop(event:Event):void
        {
            if (currentFrame == stopFrame1)
            {
                ball1.stop();
                programNumber1.text = drawnArray[0];
                ball1.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ball1stop);
            }
        }

        function ball2stop(event:Event)
        {
            if (currentFrame == stopFrame2)
            {
                ball2.stop();
                programNumber2.text = drawnArray[1];
                ball2.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ball2stop);
            }
        }

        function ball3stop(event:Event)
        {
            if (currentFrame == stopFrame3)
            {
                ball3.stop();
                programNumber3.text = drawnArray[2];
                ball3.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ball3stop);
            }
        }

        function ball4stop(event:Event)
        {
            if (currentFrame == stopFrame4)
            {
                ball4.stop();
                programNumber4.text = drawnArray[3];
                ball4.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ball4stop);
            }
        }

        function ball5stop(event:Event)
        {
            if (currentFrame == stopFrame5)
            {
                ball5.stop();
                programNumber5.text = drawnArray[4];
                ball5.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ball5stop);
            }
        }

        function bonusBallstop(event:Event)
        {
            if (currentFrame == stopFrame7)
            {
                bonusBall.stop();
                programBonusNumber.text = bonusArray[0];
                bonusBall.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bonusBallstop);
                showTimer.stop();
                fadeAndSort();
            }
        }
        if (count==0)
        {
            ball1.visible = true;

            ball1.play();
            var stopFrame1:int = 75;
            ball1stop();

        }
        else if (count==1)
        {
            ball2.visible = true;
            ball2.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ball2stop);
            ball2.play();
            var stopFrame2:int = 75;
            ball2stop();


        }
        else if (count==2)
        {
            ball3.visible = true;
            ball3.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ball3stop);
            ball3.play();
            var stopFrame3:int = 75;
            ball3stop();


        }
        else if (count==3)
        {
            ball4.visible = true;
            ball4.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ball4stop);
            ball4.play();
            var stopFrame4:int = 75;
            ball4stop();


        }
        else if (count==4)
        {
            ball5.visible = true;
            ball5.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ball5stop);
            ball5.play();
            var stopFrame5:int = 75;


        }
        else if (count==5)
        {
            ball6.visible = true;
            ball6.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ball6stop);
            ball6.play();
            var stopFrame6:int = 75;
            ball6stop();


        }
        else if (count==6)
        {
            bonusBall.visible = true;
            bonusBall.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bonusBallstop);
            bonusBall.play();
            var stopFrame7:int = 75;
            bonusballstop();

        }

    }

    count++;


    mainArray[0] = userNumber1.text;
    mainArray[1] = userNumber2.text;
    mainArray[2] = userNumber3.text;
    mainArray[3] = userNumber4.text;
    mainArray[4] = userNumber5.text;
    mainArray[5] = userNumber6.text;

}
```

Comment: why do you have functions in functions?

Comment: Because it all has to be on one file, the specification means I'm not allowed multiple external AS files.

Comment: also keep uper case words for class names:)

Answer (score 1):

I bet this is the event he has problem with:

```
event.ENTER_FRAME
```

and should be `Event.ENTER_FRAME`

also I've found this in your "code"

`function showBalls(Event:TimerEvent)`

Comment: collides with Event class used later in the addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this line at the top of your file so flash knows where to look for the Event Class

You'll also need one for Timer, TimerEvent

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
```

Comment: I've tried all the imports :( I've even tried flash.event.*; and it still won't like it.

Comment: all the lines with the ball1function or ball2function on etc

Comment: Lukasz has it - event is case sensitive

Comment: I edited the file above - you should make sure *all* the event are Event

Comment: I've edited all the "event" words to "Event" and I'm still getting "Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 2, Line 217 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Event.
"

Comment: It is. I've tried using a switch statement and it's working a tad better. But I'm still having issues.

Comment: Are you particularly familiar with flash and tweens and such Gone?

Comment: I do almost all my coding in Flash Builder and .as files.  I don't like using frames since things can get hidden quite easily.  I'd be interested in seeing how the timeline looks though.  I think there is something odd about it not working.  There is also the case of having duplicate addEventListeners

Comment: I spoke to a guy doing the same project and he pointed out a much easier way to do it. So I finally got it working. Although I am having another problem.